# How to add stitching around a polygon?

Tags: altium

I have added polygon pour on the PCB. Now I want to adding stitching just around the polygon. Look at the picture for more clarity. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to add a via? Do you know how to link the via to the appropriate netlist item?

Comment: Yes, But if I want to do it, it will take a long time. Because there are a lot of via.

Comment: You asked how to do it and, it seems, from your comment, that you know how to do it so, what's the problem here?

Comment: If Altium lets you script things conveniently, then this would be a simple thing to script. If scripting in Altium is a pain, you can export the PCB to "ASCII PCB" format, write a small Python script to add the vias (they format is very simple), then import it back to Altium.

Comment: @Andyaka In Altium ,In the tools window, an option is defined that can be used for stitching(via stitching/shielding). But it spreads the `via` s on the PCB. I wanted to just `via` around the PCB.

Comment: @kubahasn'tforgottenmonica Thanks, I didn't know that there is such capability. Do you have any tutorial link for it.

Comment: @mehdializade Not an Altium user, but can’t you just set up your grid appropriately, snap to grid and click away. Shouldn’t take long.